# How to use GROUP BY + ORDER BY + WHERE together with GET in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, post, get, where-clause

I try to make a sales report document using php and connect it from mysql database.
 How can I use where + group by + order (mysql query) with PHP get method?
I could just use SELECT and WHERE, but how to add GROUP BY and ORDER BY query?

```
$date=$_GET['date'];
$query=mysql_query("select * from product_sold where date=" . $date);
while($lihat=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $pdf->Cell(1, 0.8, $no , 1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->Cell(3, 0.8, $lihat['date'],1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->Cell(6, 0.8, $lihat['product'],1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->Cell(3, 0.8, $lihat['quantity'], 1, 0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(4, 0.8, "Rp. ".number_format($lihat['price'])." ,-", 1, 0,'C');
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

Comment: This is basic SQL and really has nothing to do with PHP

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: ...BUT your PHP interaction is poor. Don't use `mysql_` functions, don't put user input into SQL, and quote strings.

Comment: What **exactly** is the problem? Is there anything not working with the given code?

Answer (score 0):

You use GROUP BY and ORDER BY at the end of your sql statements like this...

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = $date ORDER BY desiredCategory "
```

Also, you REALLY need to be using prepared statements. You are WIDE OPEN to sql injection attacks the way you're doing this.

[More about GROUP BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)
 
[More about ORDER BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp)
[More about prepared statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the GROUP BY after you WHERE filters, then you can add the ORDER BY.

```
SELECT *
FROM product_sold
WHERE date = '$date'
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY product ASC
```

And be aware from sql injection like @jtylerm said.